# Hyperref package and ACM class.

Tags: hyperref, document-classes

I am using a Modified `acmtrans` document class. It was modified to add a custom journal.

I am having problems using the `hyperref` package.

My file has the following in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[mistar,hyperref]{acmtrans2m} 
\usepackage[pdfmark]{hyperref}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdfinfo #1#2->\pdfmark 
    {pdfmark=/DOCINFO,Title=#1,Author=#2}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `acmtrans`, use LaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.

**Background:**

The macro `\pdfmark` is defined within `pdfmark.def` which is part of the hyperref package. This will be loaded if you specify the `pdfmark` option to hyperref (which is an alias for `dvips`). However it doesn't work with pdfLaTeX: in that case another driver will be forced instead of `pdfmark.def`. You would get a warning of hyperref:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Wrong driver `hdvips.def';
(hyperref)                pdfTeX is running in PDF mode.
(hyperref)                Forcing driver `hpdftex.def'.

*hyperref using driver hpdftex*
```

Comment: I use latexmk to compile the document. Do you know the full command line, to have it use latex instead of pdflatex?

Comment: latexmk supports several options. Instead of `-pdf`, you may use `-dvi`, `-ps`, `-pdfdvi` and/or `-pdfps`. You may find documentation on http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/ .